# undesired anchor tag state change when clicked and held

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I click and hold down mouse button on anchor tags on my site, they change state ie) they shrink, grow, or change background-color.  It began recently, but I don't know when/ after what css changes I made.

I've scoured google, and here for reasoning behind what is happening with no luck.  I'm sure its a combination of css conflicts, but I can't seem to find where the conflict is with inspector.

the site is sentinel.sentinelpowersystems.com - its a bootstrap build that I have been modifying.

Any help would be great - I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed has to do with css changes made to the main.css. I found several occurrences of css selectors that applies to every element that's focused. For example in your main.css I see:

```
.accordion-toggle:hover,:focus{color: #fff;text-decoration: none;outline: 0;background-color: #2f66cb;font-size: 15px;}
```

I've formatted that a little bit below:

```
.accordion-toggle:hover,
:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #2f66cb;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

This applies to all elements with class accordion-toggle that are hovered due to `.accordion-toggle:hover` and (due to the `,`) to all elements that are hovered due to the `:focus`. I'm not sure what your intention with this, perhaps you want it to also apply to all child elements. In that case write it as:

```
.accordion-toggle:focus,
.accordion-toggle:focus * {
    ...
}
```

To find all occurrences simply search your css on `,:focus`

Comment: Thanks a ton!  It makes sense now - I thought I was adding :focus to the class by simply putting a comma after :hover.  Now I understand, I have to write it as 'class:hover,class:focus' so that it does not apply multiple instances of :focus to the all of the elements.

Comment: You're welcome! The `.foo:hover, .foo:focus` is indeed how you would write it if you want to have an effect on class `foo` for both the `:hover` and `:focus` state.